# Android Activity LaunchMode SingleTask doesn't trigger MvvmCross ViewModel constructor or Init method

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

In order to provide the correct back button behaviour of my Android app that uses MvvmCross, I've had to amend the `LaunchMode` of particular Views to `SingleTask`. Whilst this works fine, when one of these Views is used for the second time onwards, the ViewModel constructor and Init methods (used in conjuction with a `Nav` class to pass parameters from one View to another) are obviously no longer fired. I presume this is behaviour "by design" or "enforced by the Android OS" that you just need to be aware of when placing code in Constructors/Init methods that may need to be called every time the View is displayed (e.g. RefreshJobList). My fix incidentally, is to place a call to the required method in the `OnResume` method of the Activity, e.g.:

`((JobDetailViewModel)this.ViewModel).RefreshJobPhotos();`

Is there a "better way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I presume this is behaviour "by design" or "enforced by the Android OS"

If you are forcing an Activity to be `SingleTask` then it will only be created once so it will only get a ViewModel once.

There is an onNewIntent method which you could override and use to work out when this happens - MvvmCross has tried to use this in the past - but it's use has confused most developers - so currently Mvx keeps out of the way in this very specialised platform-specific area.

---

When using `SingleTask`, please be aware of Android's own warning:

> The other modes — singleTask and singleInstance — are **not appropriate for most applications**, since they result in an interaction model that is likely to be unfamiliar to users and is very different from most other applications.

from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Thanks Stuart. Using SingleTask was the only way I could create the correct behaviour of the back button but this doesn't make the app's navigation unfamiliar. It's just a typical list screen with add/update/delete record that displays a detail screen. Therefore whenever you are on the detail screen, 2 clicks of the back button will close the app rather than going back through all the instances of the list and detail screens.